# Date in X-Axis (Matplotlib Plot)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a graph based on the data from Yahoo on Google Finance.
Just starting to learn data visualisation on Pandas, Matplotlib on Jupyter Notebook.

```
google['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(google['Date'])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(google['Date'], google['Rolling Mean'], color = (0,0,0), linewidth = 4, alpha = .9, label = 'Smoothed');
ax.plot(google['Date'], google['Open'], color = (1,0,0), label = 'Original');
ax.set_title('Original and Smoothed Price')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.legend(loc='lower right')
```

Converted the date to pd.datetime but the graph showed Year-Month. How can I make it show only Year on the X-axis so that it doesn't look as crowded

I have attached an image below.

[My Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcJvv.png)
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG7Y4.png)

Comment: Are you able to post a small portion of your dataframe?

Comment: Dataframe posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib.dates`:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(google['Date'], google['Rolling Mean'], color = (0,0,0), linewidth = 4, alpha = .9, label = 'Smoothed');
ax.plot(google['Date'], google['Open'], color = (1,0,0), label = 'Original');
ax.set_title('Original and Smoothed Price')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.legend(loc='lower right')

## Format the X-axis
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
```

To get what you want (don't mind the data, I randomly generated some to plot):

[image]

Reference : https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html